# Sending parameters to sqlalchemy read_sql with pandas and sqlite connection

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to send a parameter to read_sql function using Pandas but it returns empty dataframe. The same code works perfectly when I use Ms SQL Server engine. Do I make a mistake in parameter provision? The other problem is that when I change '=' to 'like' the query works.  Here is my code:

```
    import sqlalchemy
    import pandas as pd
    import base64

    sqliteengine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///Quotes.db')
    query = "SELECT  * FROM OHLCTable WHERE nSymbol = ?  ORDER BY Date"
    self.df = pd.read_sql_query(query, sqliteengine, params= [base64.b64encode(self.listWidget.currentItem().text().encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')])
```

and here is my table schema

[image]

Comment: You can try two things here. First, the formatted strings and second pass tuple in place of a list. I believe both can potentially solve your issue.

Comment: @mad_ I really hope that by "formatted strings" you're not suggesting actually formatting the value in the query string.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see the relevant table schema, some sample data, and sample inputs, so that others may try and reproduce your findings. In other words produce a [mcve]. Since changing to LIKE works, this might be a typing issue. SQLite is peculiar in that it has dynamic typing and allows storing values of any type in any column, with affinity to the defined type of the column, which is not always what you'd expect, if coming from other DBMS.